# Activating Bluetooth on Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S2 Whenever i'm receiving the files from Another Device. It's visible only for 119 seconds. How can i visible this permanently. Is there any option to do this? Anyone guide me?

Comment: where its related with development ?? hope you know its developers forum ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is super bad idea to make this visible for ever.

Note: This is not guaranteed  to work though

Use [EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION)

or using reflection you can call `setDiscoverableTimeout()`

Also Calling `startDiscovery()` keeps the device discoverable till you call `cancelDiscovery()`. This is a device heavy procedure. So again:

- The device has the right to disobey your command
- *don't do it.*